# VlookUp in multiple columns with python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vlookup

There's a CSV file, with 1000s of entries,

It has around 50 columns out of which

> P1, P2, P3, ..... P10 are email columns in different pattern formats

They all have different emails in them

And then there is a column with **Emails** as header, which has all the correct emails but not in the sequential order (like it does not correspond to the same row values like P1, P2, ... P10 does match - they are all of a same person and in same row) so what we have to do is we have to look for emails of **Email** column (which is final correct emails) in those 10 columns(P1, P2, ... P10 - one there's pattern will match) (VLOOKUP)

So what we need is, once it's found in any one of the P's column then it should get stored in a new column with name as final email (preserving the other credentials of the row and dropping other 9 email format columns(Ps) and **Email** column and just keep one **FinalEmail** column with the matched email)

I am sharing my code below, it is not working as per expected logic used by me as it is missing almost 50 percent of matches, so I am seeking for a better working approach or fixation in the current code logic

I am sharing both csv input and output files that are coming

Take a look at the 10+1 columns from Input File
[image: A Look at the P1, P2...P10 columns and Email Column]

My Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fname=input("Enter File name: ")

df=pd.read_csv(fname)
df = df.applymap(lambda s: s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
df['Check']=np.nan

P1=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P1'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P1'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P2=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P2'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1',  'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P2'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P3=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P3'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P3'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P4=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P4'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P3',  'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P4'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P5=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P5'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4',  'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P5'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P6=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P6'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P6'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P7=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P7'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6',  'P8', 'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P7'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P8=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P8'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7',  'P9','P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P8'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P9=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P9'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P10', 'Email']) ]
df.loc[df['P9'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P10=df.loc[(df['Check'].isna()) & df['P10'].isin(df['Email']),~df.columns.isin(['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9', 'Email'])] 
df.loc[df['P10'].isin(df['Email']), "Check"] = "True"

P1.rename({'P1': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P2.rename({'P2': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P3.rename({'P3': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P4.rename({'P4': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P5.rename({'P5': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P6.rename({'P6': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P7.rename({'P7': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P8.rename({'P8': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P9.rename({'P9': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
P10.rename({'P10': 'FinalEmail'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

edf=pd.DataFrame()
final = edf.append([P1,P2, P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10])
print(len(final), len(final.drop_duplicates()))

final.to_csv('Output - '+fname)
```

[Project Folder with relevant files on Gdrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MspIg9aoLh13Yhi2syKpk7QqN9LpKeRl?usp=sharing)

I am sharing a sample data of 10 rows from the csv too

[Sample 10 rows as data from Input CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B3DRz_vb2u8o5_0ypKW7G6YKJnVykiZB/view?usp=sharing)

[Output of above Sample 10 rows CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A-D4PUxq4mRCd8QIxOSIxu6EFH9x9fdg/view?usp=sharing)

[Sample 100 rows as data from Input CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KGBeCdfLYY-oHsjcsxHIfRQWryUrBlII/view?usp=sharing)

[Output of above Sample 100 rows CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QdJBYpZBkH-QkbgvtS6cS6Ql8oq_kjJJ/view?usp=sharing)

[Python Script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/145CZWbTCpacJm5s5ueMpX_mFeJ9CNvyD/view?usp=sharing)

[Jupter Notebook / Google Collab Script (Online)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CJq1tE8ZmWveZcU5qCOKwhsgsYOSdZPa/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the logic/script I have posted, I have tried the same script on other multiple input files, the input file that I have posted was not upto the output I was expecting, output is still correct for logic.